# generating a function call depth using python for source files written in C

Tags: python-2.7

I have to find out whether a list of variables are modified inside a function written in C using python.The source files to browse are written in C. And there are around 2000 files and around 1000  variables in my project. The main reason of this script is basically to check the data consistency between interrupt handling of different coprocessors.

e.g.

Variable List = [var_w,var_x,var_y,var_z]

```
        /*Module 1.c*/

           ISR ()

                {



                    var_x++;

                    fun_y();

                    fun_z();



                    }
```

/* end of the module 1*/

/* modul2.c */

```
           fun_y() {var_y = 1;}
```

/* module3.c */

```
           fun_z() { fun_zz();}

           fun_zz() {var_z ++;}
```

/*****************************/

```
           ISR

               ->fun_y

               ->fun_z

                         ->fun_zz

               ->....

                       ->

                          .....

                               ..........
```

So the result of the script shall be like  var_x ,var_y,var_z are modified by the ISR.

Could you please suggest me a better way of doing it ?

Will it help to use python Yacc ?

Thanking you.

With best regards

Comment: Why do you have to do it? And why do you have to do it in python? You seem to be asking something different than you really want. It does not look like reasonable way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: I want to find out whether a líst of variables modified by a ISR using script. And the script is going to be used in many project variants.  Thanks

Comment: You just said nothing more than previously. You need to provide more context and a reason _why_ you need them. And you should _edit the question_.

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck.

Theoretically speaking, in its general case, deciding whether a program/function changes a variable (i.e. without running the program) is an [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).  If it were decidable, one could easily solve the halting problem using the program deciding whether a program changes a variable (by reduction).

You could come up with a partial solution, to find *some* of the cases where variables get changed.  But it sounds like it isn't worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the proposed script is not intended to find out any run time anamolies. Only it is needed to check whether a variable used in both ISR and outside. Thanks !!